# Core image CIImage 8 bit grayscale

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, image-processing, core-image

I want to do 2 things:
1) Load 8 bit grayscale image as 8 but grayscale image
2) Save it as 8 bit grayscale image

I try to load image to CIImage via [CIImage imageWithContentsOfURL:options]`. 
As I understand I can specify some  options in item options. But I didn't find any information how to do it. In reference of CIImage I found only these pixel formats:

```
extern CIFormat kCIFormatARGB8;
extern CIFormat kCIFormatRGBA16;
extern CIFormat kCIFormatRGBAf;
extern CIFormat kCIFormatRGBAh;
```

What does it mean? I can't load and save 8 bit grayscale images via CIImage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no format for 8 bit grayscale. What is it you're trying to do? There are other ways to create an image using 8-bit grayscale, but without more info, it's hard to tell you what to suggest.

If you are going to use CoreImage to manipulate it, you'll need to put it into one of the RGB formats mentioned above. But if you're not going to use CoreImage to manipulate it, you might be able to create an `NSImage` (by creating an [`NSBitmapImageRep`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/applicationkit/classes/nsbitmapimagerep_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000347-DontLinkElementID_4)) or a CGImage (see [`CGImageCreate()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGImage/Reference/reference.html)) in the format you want.

Comment: I want to do 2 things: 1) Change geometry(like resizing, crop, and Canvas) 2) I want to change brightness/contrast im my image. For 2nd task I wanted to use filters in Image Core.

Comment: Well you're right, CoreImage would be the easiest way to do so. You can either load the image in RGB and do your manipulations with CoreImage, then save it back out as grayscale. (None of those operations you mention should add color.) Or you could do it with OpenGL using glsl, which is more involved. (Or you could write your own CPU-based filters, which is also a lot of work.)

Answer (score 0):

Saving a CIImage to a grayscale image format is as simple as this:

```
CGColorSpaceRef cs = CGColorSpaceCreateWithName(kCGColorSpaceGenericGrayGamma2_2);
NSData *outData = [ctx PNGRepresentationOfImage:input
                          format:kCIFormatL8
                          colorSpace:cs
                          options:@{}];
```